# ValueError when trying to save ndarray (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, save

I am trying to translate a project I have in MATLAB to Python+Numpy because MATLAB keeps running out of memory. The file I have is rather long, so I have tried to make a minimal example that shows the same error.

Basically I'm making a 2d histogram of a dataset, and want to save it after some processing. The problem is that the numpy.save function throws a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" when I try to save the output of the histogram function. I can't find the problem when I look at the docs of Numpy.

My version of Python is 2.6.6, Numpy version 1.4.1 on a Debian distro.

```
import numpy as np
import random

n_samples = 5
rows      = 5

out_file = file('dens.bin','wb')

x_bins = np.arange(-2.005,2.005,0.01)
y_bins = np.arange(-0.5,n_samples+0.5)

listy = [random.gauss(0,1) for r in range(n_samples*rows)]

dens = np.histogram2d( listy, \
       range(n_samples)*rows, \
       [y_bins, x_bins])

print 'Write data'
np.savez(out_file, dens)
out_file.close()
```

Full output:

```
$ python error.py 
Write data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.py", line 19, in <module>
    np.savez(out_file, dens)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/lib/io.py", line 439, in savez
    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 312, in asanyarray
   return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: your code works for me on Ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7 and numpy 1.6.1

Comment: That's weird. I experimented some more: using the pickle library does work for saving.

Comment: The help of the 'savez' says `np.savez(file, *args, **kwds)`. I have the feeling the your version of numpy does not unpack lists. Can you try with `np.savez(out_file, *dens)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `np.histogram2d` actually returns a tuple of three arrays: `(hist, x_bins, y_bins)`.  If you want to save all three of these, you have to unpack them as @Francesco said.

```
dens = np.histogram2d(listy,
                      range(n_samples)*rows,
                      [y_bins, x_bins])
np.savez('dens.bin', *dens)
```

Alternatively, if you only need the histogram itself, you could save just that.

```
np.savez('dens.bin', dens[0])
```

If you want to keep track of which of these is which, use the `**kwds` instead of the `*args`

```
denskw = dict(zip(['hist','y_bins','x_bins'], dens))
np.savez('dens.bin', **denskw)
```

Then, you can load it like

```
dens = np.load('dens.bin')
hist = dens['hist']# etc
```